# Diagnosing ASP.NET MVC time spent before controller is invoked

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, glimpse

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET and I'm trying to understand why my site is sometimes running very slowly.  Sometimes requests will take 20+ seconds and then a moment later they take less than one second.  In an effort to track down the issue I have installed both Application Insights and Glimpse.  They both revealed that something is taking a long time before my controller is even being invoked.  In the screenshot from Glimpse below you can see that 20 seconds elapsed between when the request was started and when the controller was first invoked(see screenshot).  My question is how do I begin to track down where that time is going?[image: Example of Glimpse capture]

Other information that might be relevant:

- I'm using Unity for dependency injection
- I'm using Elmah and a SQL Azure database for request logging
- I'm using Entity Framework 6 Code First for database interaction
- The site is being run in Windows Azure as a web role in a Cloud Service
- Authentication is being handled by Azure Active Directory

Update 5/17/2016:
In response to nikmd23's comment, here is the list of HTTP modules that are being used.
[image: List of HTTP modules being used.]

We also did some digging on our end and using Application Insight's real-time metric view we saw that the CPU was spiking to 100% for a second or two even when no requests were being processed.  After some more digging it turned out that AgentCore.exe was the culprit.  We never did identify a clear root cause, we just simply deleted the Cloud Service and re-created it and now the problem appears to be resolved.

Comment: Does this only occur when you haven't accessed the site in a while? Is there any chance that your actual application pool has timed out and has to spin back up again? Newer versions of IIS resolved this by using the [App Suspend](http://rion.io/2013/10/10/remove-slow-startups-and-enjoy-less-suspense-through-net-4-5-1s-app-suspend-feature/) feature to allow the applications that do time-out to be quickly accessed again.

Comment: Application pool recycling was one of my first suspicions as well.  So the first thing that I did was setup endpoint monitoring in Azure so that something would be pinging the site on regular occasion and thus the app pool shouldn't get suspended.  That didn't help.  Additionally, I have seen the slow behavior even if we're actively using the site.

Comment: What HTTP Modules do you have in play? Glimpse will show you that on the Configuration tab.

Comment: Did you find out what was causing this issue?

Comment: No, @JMac we never did get to a root cause.  Since re-creating the Cloud Service seemed to magically make the problem go away, we just moved on.  Sorry.